# In RUBY Sort a table by a field

Tags: ruby, sorting

I need to sort (ascending order) a table by a field.

This is my table:

```
    vTable=Text::Table.new
    vTable.head= ["Value", "Rest", "NumberRun"]
```

I store my data in the table inside a loop

```
    lp= [value, rest, num]
    vTable.rows << lp
```

After completing my table, it looks like:

```
 33183   | 109        | 5.10.0.200
 34870   | 114        | 5.4.1.100
 28437   | 93         | 5.6.0.050 
 31967   | 105        | 5.6.2.500 
 29942   | 98         | 5.7.2.900
```

I would like to sort, ascending order, this table by "NumberRun" considering that 5.10.0.200 is bigger than 5.7.2.900.

My idea was to remove "." from "NumberRun", convert it into a number, and then sort. In this way 5.10.x > 5.9.x

Comment: Where does `Text::Table` come from?

Comment: Allows you to create and format plain text tables. it is easy printing formatted tables to a dot-matrix printer using that

Comment: Have you tried `vTable.rows.sort_by { |_,_,run| convert(run) }`?

Comment: It seems that you are using the [`text-table`](https://github.com/aptinio/text-table) gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the rows the following way. It uses the [`Array#sort_by!()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-sort_by-21) method, which was introduced with Ruby 1.9.2.

```
vTable.rows.sort_by! { |_,_,num| num.split('.').map(&:to_i) }
```

It also uses Destructuring for the block parameters of `sort_by!()`.

For Ruby versions older than 1.9.2 you can sort the `rows` and reassign them.

```rb
vTable.rows = vTable.rows.sort_by { |_,_,num| num.split('.').map(&:to_i) }
```

Comment: I obtain this error -> undefined method `sort_by!' for #<Array:0x7f9f4d9d4808>

Comment: What Ruby version do you use? I assigned an standard array at the begin, `vTable.rows = []`.

Comment: aaazzzzzz probably an old versio -> ruby 1.8.7

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Same idea, isn't it?

Comment: yep, and I got the same error "undefined method `sort_by!' for #<Array:0x7f9f4d9d4808>". Probably it is due to my old version of ruby.. but the problem is that I cannot update my system..

Comment: yea, but my solution does not use `sort_by!`, but `sort_by` which works on Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Try to reassign the `rows` attribute as workaround, `vTable.rows = vTable.rows.sort_by! { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a NumberRun class for you that can do the comparision.

```
#number_run.rb
class NumberRun
  include Comparable
  attr_accessor :run_number
  def initialize(str)
    @run_number = str
  end

  def <=> str1
    str_split = @run_number.split(".")
    str1_split = str1.run_number.split(".")
    output = 0
    str_split.each_with_index do |num, index|
      if((num.to_i <=> str1_split[index].to_i) != 0 && index != (str_split.count - 1))
        output = (num.to_i <=> str1_split[index].to_i)
        break
      elsif index == (str_split.count - 1)
        output = (num.to_i <=> str1_split[index].to_i)
      end
    end
    output
  end
end
```

For an example:

```
a = [
  NumberRun.new('5.10.0.200'),
  NumberRun.new('5.4.1.100'),
  NumberRun.new('5.6.0.050'),
  NumberRun.new('5.6.2.500'),
  NumberRun.new('5.7.2.900')
]

a.sort.map(&:run_number)
```